# Angular $http.post gives Error: Invalid argument. in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs

App works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox etc. But in IE the following code gives an error:

```
$http.post('/myurl', 55)
  .success(...)
  .error(...)
```

The error:

```
Error: Invalid argument.
```

Happens after `$rootScope.$digest();` in the `$apply` function in `angular.js`

Any ideas that could help debugging this mysterious Microsoft Internet Explorer™ error message?

Comment: Can you show us the entire method? Is this in controller, directive or service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so... I turns out adding quotes makes IE happy.

This works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. :

```
$http.post('/myurl', myNumberVariable)
```

But fails in IE (8). However, this works in IE 8:

```
$http.post('/myurl', myNumberVariable.toString())
```

Didn't get clarification if this was due to angular or the java backend method that was tried to call.

Comment: This fixed an $http.put(url, content) call in IE9 for me

Comment: And a post for me in IE8 & 9. Thanks @Cotten. Painful IE development :(

Comment: This also solved an IE9 issue for me. Is there an angular bug registered for this? Sounds like a simple fix.

Comment: Also a resolved IE9 issue here. I don't think that this is a back-end problem because I don't see Internet Explorer sending any packets on post.